# I am building my docker image from ReactJS, why is my docker build failing?

Tags: node.js, docker, canvas, apple-m1, node-gyp

I'm trying to build a docker image and I am getting the following error in my terminal output:

```
[+] Building 82.8s (10/11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12.10                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.0s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3.8s
 => => transferring context: 139.71MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    3.8s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.10@sha256:cda22332e2dd46807a14d3268ee3fb298651386ad1f03cfd58772a7dc65f89c7                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY package.json package.json                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN yarn                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                77.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 > [5/6] RUN yarn:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#10 0.336 yarn install v1.17.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#10 0.378 [1/5] Validating package.json...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#10 0.379 [2/5] Resolving packages...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#10 0.535 [3/5] Fetching packages...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#10 24.99 info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
#10 24.99 info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
#10 24.99 [4/5] Linking dependencies...
#10 24.99 warning " > @date-io/date-fns@1.3.11" has incorrect peer dependency "date-fns@2.1.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > @material-ui/pickers@3.3.10" has unmet peer dependency "@date-io/core@^1.3.6".
#10 24.99 warning " > @material-ui/pickers@3.3.10" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > bootstrap@4.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.14.3".
#10 24.99 warning " > react-moment@0.8.4" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > awesome-typescript-loader@3.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@^2".
#10 24.99 warning " > babel-loader@7.1.5" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@2 || 3 || 4".
#10 24.99 warning " > extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.1.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > file-loader@1.1.11" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@1 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3".
#10 24.99 warning " > sass-loader@6.0.7" has incorrect peer dependency "node-sass@^4.0.0".
#10 24.99 warning " > sass-loader@6.0.7" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
#10 28.32 [5/5] Building fresh packages...
#10 28.69 warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/src/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt: Command failed.
#10 28.69 Exit code: 1
#10 28.69 Command: node install.js
#10 28.69 Arguments: 
#10 28.69 Directory: /src/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
#10 28.69 Output:
#10 28.69 PhantomJS not found on PATH
#10 28.69 Unexpected platform or architecture: linux/arm64
#10 28.69 It seems there is no binary available for your platform/architecture
#10 28.69 Try to install PhantomJS globally"
#10 28.69 info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
#10 30.05 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#10 30.05 error /src/node_modules/canvas: Command failed.
#10 30.05 Exit code: 1
#10 30.05 Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
#10 30.05 Arguments: 
#10 30.05 Directory: /src/node_modules/canvas
#10 30.05 Output:
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.5
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp info using node@12.10.0 | linux | arm64
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v72-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v72-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz 
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@12.10.0 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v72-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz 
#10 30.05 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#10 30.05 gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
#10 30.05 gyp info using node@12.10.0 | linux | arm64
#10 30.05 gyp info ok 
#10 30.05 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#10 30.05 gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
#10 30.05 gyp info using node@12.10.0 | linux | arm64
#10 30.05 gyp info find Python using Python version 3.5.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
#10 30.05 gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.10.0/node-v12.10.0-headers.tar.gz
#10 30.05 gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.10.0/node-v12.10.0-headers.tar.gz
#10 30.05 gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt
#10 30.05 gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args [
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '/src/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-f',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   'make',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-I',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '/src/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-I',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '/src/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-I',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.10.0',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/src/node_modules/node-gyp',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/src/node_modules/canvas',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   'build',
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
#10 30.05 gyp info spawn args ]
#10 30.05 Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
#10 30.05 Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
#10 30.05 to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
#10 30.05 No package 'pangocairo' found
#10 30.05 gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! configure error 
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/src/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/src/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! cwd /src/node_modules/canvas
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
#10 30.05 gyp ERR! not ok 
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /src/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/src/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /src/node_modules/canvas
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.5
#10 30.05 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
#10 30.05 Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /src/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
------
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.10

WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

RUN yarn

COPY . . 

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

I have tried `brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg` (the x86_64 install with Rosetta 2) per https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1684.

- Do I need to try to uninstall and reinstall node-gyp?

Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

**I added the necessary dependencies to my Dockerfile but am now getting the following error:**

```
[+] Building 5.7s (6/11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 347B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12.10                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.6s
 => => transferring context: 2.42MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.6s
 => CACHED [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.10@sha256:cda22332e2dd46807a14d3268ee3fb298651386ad1f03cfd58772a7dc65f89c7                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [2/7] RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libcairo-dev  pk-config  cairo  pango  libpng  jpeg  giflib  librsvg *                                                                                                                                          5.3s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 > [2/7] RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libcairo-dev  pk-config  cairo  pango  libpng  jpeg  giflib  librsvg *:                                                                                                                                                     
#5 0.257 Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [53.0 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                 
#5 0.421 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#5 0.455 Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages [698 kB]                                                                                                                                                                        
#5 0.455 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [93.6 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                               
#5 0.590 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
#5 0.737 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [3177 B]
#5 0.822 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages [6921 kB]
#5 4.597 Fetched 7886 kB in 4s (1791 kB/s)
#5 4.597 Reading package lists...
#5 4.926 Reading package lists...
#5 5.243 Building dependency tree...
#5 5.301 Reading state information...
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package pk-config
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package cairo
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package pango
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package libpng
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package jpeg
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package giflib
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package librsvg
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package bin
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package boot
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package dev
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package etc
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package home
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package lib
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package media
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package mnt
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package proc
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package root
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package run
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package sbin
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package srv
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package sys
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package tmp
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package usr
#5 5.311 E: Unable to locate package var
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -y install libcairo-dev  pk-config  cairo  pango  libpng  jpeg  giflib  librsvg *]: exit code: 100
```

**Updated Dockerfile:**

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y install libcairo-dev \
 pk-config \
 cairo \
 pango \
 libpng \
 jpeg \
 giflib \
 librsvg *

WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

RUN yarn install

COPY . . 

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: This looks like it's `docker build` output; can you edit the question to include your Dockerfile as well?  (Anything you `brew install` on the host won't be visible inside the image.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I added my `Dockerfile`.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to `apt-get install` those OS-level dependencies in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install those dependencies inside a docker build not on your machine.

Sample Dockerfile based on yours would be:

```
FROM node:12.10

# Note the dependency install
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libcairo-dev -y

WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

RUN yarn

COPY . . 

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

Of course, that's only a start and you have to add all required dependencies.

Comment: @David Maze @kuba So would I essentially have to write a separate `RUN` command for every dependency/devdependency in my `package.json`?

Comment: @BlakeLucey Actually not, casue you don't install dependencies from `package.json` but the system dependencies required _for_ dependencies from `pacakge.json`. In your particular example `canvas` wanted to compile a binary that requires `cairo` (ofc, `canvas` module does not have to be your direct dependency in `package.json`)

Comment: So based on my understanding, I will need to install dependencies such as `pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg` to support the dependencies within `package.json` that are being copied over into my docker image.  Is that more accurate?

Comment: @BlakeLucey yes, but INSIED the docker image with `apt-get install libcairo-dev librsvg jpeg ...` and so one (Linke in the example aboce). You can pass multiple packages name to the `apt-get install command`. `-dev` versions of those libraries may also be required but you'll see along the way what's required.

Comment: I am now showing a new error in my terminal output.  The packages added to my Dockerfile can't be located.  I updated my question with the terminal output and the updated Dockerfile.  If you are able to provide input that would be appreciated.  Thanks.